# Set milliseconds of Stopwatch

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently working on a Flutter Time Tracking application where I use the Stopwatch class from dart:core. Therfore, I would like to set the initial value of the Stopwatch.

However, all of the the fields like elapsedMilliseconds are readonly.

So this is not working:

```
_stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds = 5000
```

Is it possible to change the Stopwatch class, so I can set the elapsed time on creation or dynamically.

Comment: you want a count down timer right?

Comment: I think what you probably want to do, depending on where you are using this, is either create an offset, and add that to the elapsed time where you use it, or create a wrapper around the stopwatch class that takes an offset and adds it to the result for it's own elapsed time methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't possible with the StopWatch class as you've discovered; it is intended to just be very simple and so just implements start/stop/reset.

If you're wanting to be able to create a stopwatch that has additional features such as an initial value, changing elapsed time, etc... then I'd recommend writing a wrapper class. That could be something like:

```
class StopwatchEx {

  final Stopwatch _stopWatch = Stopwatch();
  Duration _initialOffset;

  StopwatchEx({Duration initialOffset = Duration.zero}):
    _initialOffset = initialOffset;

  start() => _stopWatch.start();

  stop() => _stopWatch.stop();

  reset({Duration newInitialOffset = null}) {
    _stopWatch.reset();
    _initialOffset = newInitialOffset ?? _initialOffset;
  }

  Duration get elapsed => _stopWatch.elapsed + _initialOffset;

  ...
}
```